# Is it possible to create alert to the moogsoft from condition on sql table column value

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

Is it possible to create alert to the moogsoft from condition on  sql table column value

Comment: once we integrate moogsoft to azure we can create alerts through webhook

Answer (score -1):

One of the workarounds is to use the `HTTP webhook` connector from Logic Apps to call  `Moogsoft Cloud Ingestion Services` endpoint.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Codit - Consuming Webhooks with Logic Apps](https://www.codit.eu/blog/consuming-webhooks-with-logic-apps/?country_sel=be)
2. [Moogsoft - Azure integration](https://docs.moogsoft.com/en/azure-integration.html)

Comment: except logic apps is their anyway to create alert on moogsoft from data factory and then calling webhook

Comment: @heenashaikh you can use data factory or function app too.

Comment: how to pass the condition from sql table data through data factory ?